# Search with special character "-" not working in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I have Customer data indexed in Apache Solr with details such as name, address, contact numbers, birth date, etc.

I am trying to search the index with the following query, but couldn't get any results.

```
http://locahost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=address:ATA-1234
```

here the special character "-" is used to search the contact number field.

- Tired with escape backslash as per the document (https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_3/the-standard-query-parser.html#escaping-special-characters), but no results

```
http://locahost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=address:ATA\-1234
http://locahost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=address:"ATA\-1234"
http://locahost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=address:"ATA-1234"
```

- Tried with **KeywordTokenizerFactory** and **WhitespaceTokenizerFactory** (https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_2/tokenizers.html#keyword-tokenizer), but no results
- Will Text Analysis be performed on Wildcard and Fuzzy search? Does the below query work?

```
http://locahost:8983/solr/customer/select?q=contact:*01\-1234*
```

Can someone please clarify the above queries?

Comment: how is behaviour in the solr analysis page? could you please check there as well?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti From the Analysis page, able to query the records.

Comment: In general, filters are not applied to wildcard searches. What is the content of the field you're trying to match against? If the value has been tokenized differently than what you're trying to do when searching, you won't get a hit. Changing the tokenizer (unless just for the query analysis) _will_ require reindexing your content before attempting to search against it.

Comment: @MatsLindh The field content is a list of JSON values. I am trying to search for one of the values for the key NAME from the JSON. Both Index and Query analyzer use the same Tokenizing method. I am aware that, reindexing requires if we change the tokenizer.

Comment: If it's verbatim JSON, it'll be hard to make it behave properly. Using the StandardTokenizer will (probably) break `"ATA-1234"` into `ATA`  and `1234`. If you use the whitespacetokenizer, there isn't any whitespace - so `"ATA-1234"` will be stored verbatim. You'll probably be far better off actually processing the JSON into separate, proper fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query works well with forward-slash (**/**).

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/tech_products/select?q=name:ata/-133
```

**Example** :
Input Value : "Samsung SpinPoint P120 SP2514N - hard drive - 250 GB - ATA-133"

With StandardTokenizer, the value is split into tokens as below

```
ST Samsung  SpinPoint P120  SP2514N hard drive  250 GB  ATA 133
```

With ClassicTokenizer, the value is split into tokens as below.

```
ST Samsung  SpinPoint P120  SP2514N hard drive  250 GB  ATA-133
```